# HTML CSS grid 3x3 with divs

Tags: css, html

I'm no novice at HTML/PHP. Just... A bit somewhat incapable. I need something like this:

[image: ss of diagram]

I know its only a rough sketch, and rough being an under estimate, but could someone help? preferably done in html css.

If anyone can help, could you work to this?

```
Width: 900px 
bg colour:e9e9e9 
align:center 
Top, bottom, left and right side images repeat 
Corner images don't repeat 
Corner images: 40 x 40 
Side/top/bottom images: repeat
```

I have this so far: [jsfiddle](http://bit.ly/17lsBVK)

Comment: First, are you sure you need divs ? Maybe it could be better with table ?

Will it be needed to expand it or will it stay still ?

Comment: I need it to stay a fixed size and have no gaps between the central content div and the surrounding divs. I need them to wrap onto the central div.

Comment: Are you sure you need images? If you just need rounded corners, shadows, borders and stuff like that, you could use CSS3 instead.

Comment: I cant achieve 2 tone images? like this: http://imgur.com/8SHGJSi

Comment: You mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/kDTrR/1/

Comment: could you use some CSS3? http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image (http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image) or do you need to do it the old school way?

Comment: Maybe a framework for grids could be of any use? If you're new to web development, you should look into Bootstrap, which provides a solution for grids and a number of other useful features. And it's easy to use! http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be useful : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kDTrR/46/)

Basically it's a HTML cover with basic CSS and images added for exemple.
You only need now to add the size and color you wish to add in the `CSS` properties, such as :

```
width : 900px;
background-color : #E9E9E9;
align : center
```

Your exemple was good, but I think you would have maybe had a better result by doing only the HTML first, and then the CSS.
If you allow me to give you an advice, you should do the positionning of `divs` with a simple CSS such as `border : 1px solid black; height : 15px; width : 15px`, and make a strong HTML code based on that. Then switch to CSS to make it look good.
And at last, you may add the content.

Comment: You should consider making this a comment.  It's not really an answer